# Geodjango - User's uploaded shapefiles and model creation

Tags: geodjango

I have a big interrogation about how it could be possible to have a GeoDjango app that can store in database the uploaded shapefiles (or other geospatial files) from users. When you load shapefiles in GeoDjango, you have to create a new model that matches the fields of the shapefile. How could it be possible to create a new model automatically each time a user uploads a files? You can't append the new model definition to your models.py each time? For me, that does not make any sense.

Does it means the best way is to use a generic model definition and only allow files upload that match this definition,and then to create a new instance of this generic model? Can someone explain me what is the best practice to create an app that can store users uploaded spatial files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, adding a new model to models.py each time is impossible. And, if it where, you would end up with a lot of unmanageable tables.

One option is to use a schema-less datastore (i.e. a NoSQL database) but then you'd loose the spaial capabilities of PostGIS (or have to use both PostGIS and a NoSQL db, no fun!). And then there's the concept of "[hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html)" in PostgreSQL which allows you to store a set of key/value pairs in a single column. Unfortunately, the [django-hstore lib](https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore) requires its own db.backend definition, this would result in a conflict with the geodjango-backend.

This means that the solution I would recommend is one described in the book "[Python Geospatial Development](http://www.packtpub.com/python-geospatial-development/book)". I'll just outline the approach here, either you get the idea or you could get yourself a copy of the book for a more thourough explaination.

In brief:

Model your app like this:

```py
class Shapefile(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    srs = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    geom_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    encoding = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    shapefile = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    precision = models.IntegerField()

class Feature(models.Model):
    shapefile = models.ForeignKey(Shapefile)
    geom_point = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=true)
    geom_multipoint = models.MultiPointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=true)
    geom_multilinestring = models.MultiLineStringField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=true)
    geom_multipolygon = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=true)
    geom_geometrycollection = models.GeometryCollectionField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=true)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=true)
```

In this way the shapefile schema is modeled in a set of relations

Comment: you can combine django-hstore backend with geodjango backend easily: follow this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/3YHKru_EaCg . The problem with this kind of generic models is the slowness when you upload table with many features. You can also take a look at dynamic models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I think that the real solution for this issue is not yet created. We need a plugin in geodjango that will connect to uploaded tables in database maybe without model definition.

Comment: Seeing that this question has recieved some interest lately I just want to point out that PostgreSQL now supports schemaless data, using json or hstore (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html)

Comment: That's great! Would you prefer hstore or json tought?

Comment: I think the Layermapping module will help reduce overhead here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/